# Make a rounded ImageButton

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I try to make round corners to an imageButton in Android Studio but it doesn't work. It works fine with an image or a normal button. This is the code:

buttons_cocktails.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="?colorAccent" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/linear1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

 <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/vodka_orange"
     android:layout_width="150dp"
     android:layout_height="150dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
     android:alpha="0.90"
     android:scaleType="centerInside"
     android:src="@drawable/vodka_orange"
     android:background="@drawable/buttons_cocktails"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try once -
This is for circular background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="?colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

and this is for rounded corners

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="?colorAccent" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
         android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

and

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/vodka_orange"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_cocktails"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

change image and color as per your requirement.

Comment: Nothing happened. I mean the imageButton is above the customized button. If i make the image button smaller i can see the pattern :|